# One dictionary key is overriding the others. Dictionary is being accessed at definition

Tags: python, django, dictionary, view

I am experiencing an odd issue where 21 of the dictionary keys work correctly. However, when this specific 22nd one is added, things stop working correctly. The dictionary is accessed when being defined as well as being immediately accessed always with the 22nd key (whether it is correct or not). The dictionary is inside of a Django function view that aims to edit Product forms and save them to a quotation. Below is the template and url as well as function view.

`{% url 'quote:edit_line_item' pk=quote.pk product_name=item.product_name line_item=item.pk%}`

`re_path(r'quote/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit-line-item/(?P<product_name>.+)/(?P<line_item>\d+)/$', views.add_to_quote, name = 'edit_line_item')`

```
def add_to_quote(request,*args,**kwargs):
    pk = kwargs['pk']


    if kwargs.get('line_item') == None:

        product_template_form = 'quote/product_template_form.html'

        form_dict = {
            'FilterProduct':FilterProductForm(request.POST,initial={'quote':pk},user=request.user),
            'Product1': Product1Form(request.POST,initial={'quote':pk},
            'Product2': Product2Form(request.POST,initial={'quote':pk},
            ...
            'Product21':Product21Form(request.POST,initial={'quote':pk},
        }
        form = form_dict[request.POST['product_name']]
    else:
        obj = get_object_or_404(model_dict[kwargs['product_name']],
         pk=kwargs['line_item'])
        print(f"object {obj}")
        print(kwargs)

        product_template_form = 'quote/edit_product_form.html'

        print("here")
        form_dict = {
            "FilterProduct": FilterProductForm(request.POST or None,
            initial={'quote':kwargs['pk']}, instance = obj,user=request.user),
            # "FilterProduct": print("why am I printing?"),
            'Product1': Product1Form(request.POST or None,
            initial={'quote':kwargs['pk']}, instance = obj),
            'Product2': Product2Form(request.POST or None,
            initial={'quote':kwargs['pk']}, instance = obj),
          ...
            'Product21': Product21Form(request.POST or None,
            initial={'quote':kwargs['pk']}, instance = obj),
    

        }

        print("there")
        print(kwargs.get('product_name'))
        form = form_dict[str(kwargs.get('product_name'))]
        ...continues from here with logic

    return render(request, product_template_form, {'form':form})
```

Since the `line_item` kwarg is provided the else statement of the function is ran. I have print statements above and below the `form_dict` as a means of tracing the error. Below is the output when `product_name` is `Product1`. The `there` print statement never runs because the `form_dict` is incorrectly accessed with the `FilterProduct` key.

```
object Product1 object (139)
{'pk': '44', 'product_name': 'Product1', 'line_item': '139'}
here
Internal Server Error: /quote/44/edit-line-item/Product1/139/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jackson/.venvs/configurator/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jackson/.venvs/configurator/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jackson/.venvs/configurator/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jackson/projects/configurator/quote/views.py", line 328, in add_to_quote
    "FilterProduct": FilterProductForm(request.POST or None,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

If I uncomment the `FilterProduct` key and use the key that is currently commented, the function runs successfully in displaying the Product1 form with instance data. I can tell the `FilterProduct` key is still being accessed at definition from the output below:

```
object Product1 object (139)
{'pk': '44', 'product_name': 'Product1', 'line_item': '139'}
here
why am I printing?
there
Product1
[21/Oct/2021 19:56:58] "GET /quote/44/edit-line-item/Product1/139/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5078
```

Again, if the `FilterProduct` key is added into the `form_dict`, it is immediately accessed upon definition and I have no clue why. Any insight would be really appreciated.

FilterProductForm init method

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        print(str(kwargs['instance']))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        sales_office = user.profile.office

        products_without_filters = ['WRC', 'WRC FQ', 'NRC ARR. B', 'NRC ARR. C',
                                    'NRC ARR. D', 'LVN', 'NonConfig','Filters']

        self.fields['filter'].queryset = Filter.objects.none()
        print(f"this is self.data {self.data}")
        if 'product' in self.data:
            try:

                product = ProductSelect.objects.get(id=self.data['product'])
                self.fields['filter'].queryset = Filter.objects.filter(product=product)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['filter'].queryset = self.instance.product.filter_set

        self.fields['product'].queryset = ProductSelect.objects.filter(aaf_office=sales_office).exclude(product__in=products_without_filters)
```

Modifying the elif condition and changing the str method in the model for FilterProduct to "Filter". I was able to get things functioning correctly. I still do not understand why the init method executes when being defined in the dictionary.

```
elif str(self.instance) == "Filter" and self.instance.pk:
```

Comment: Could you please share the `FilterProductForm` details.

Comment: It's complaining about the `user=` kwarg passed to FilterProductForm, which isn't a feature of the other forms. `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'` refers to `FilterProductForm.__init__`.

Comment: I figured out the issue! I apologize for the slightly incorrect traceback. I thought the init method was the issue so I commented it out, which is why the unexpected keyword argument 'user', popped up. Turns out it was the init method. I was modifying it as I needed the logic to help run an ajax request. Below is if statement that is in the init method, specifically it is the elif condition that is causing error. I have the fix dropped into the question as well.